# Translating a string from a database (localisation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on globalization and localisation of my web applications in .NET MVC5. This works fine for my static strings, but I also wan't to translate some text called from a database. My setup is like this:

I have a resource folder with 2 resource files, one English version (Resource.resx) and one Dutch (Resource.nl-NL.resx). In these files are my translations. Then I have a Helper folder with my CultureHelper class, and I have a BaseController. My Homecontroller is extended by my BaseController. In my ViewModels I refer to the translations like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
```

This all works just fine, but I also have some strings / fields that are stored in a database. I also want to translate those fields. But I do not know how.

This is the part where I call for the fields (and the value of the fields, I don't want to translate the the value, only the fieldName).

```
foreach (var fieldName in Model.LineViewAttributeNames)
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
           @fieldName  
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedLineView))
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LineViewItems.First(lvi => lvi.Id == Model.SelectedLineView)
                        .LineFieldAttributes.Single(lfa => lfa.Name == fieldName).Value, null, fieldName, null)
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="text" name="@fieldName" />
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Can someone help me explain how to translate the `fieldNames`?

**EDIT, the answer to my question**

In my helper:

```
public static string GetLabel(string fieldName)           
    {
        ResourceManager resMngr = new ResourceManager("Project.Resources.Resource", typeof(Resources.Resource).Assembly);
        return resMngr.GetString(fieldName, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
    }
```

In my view:

```
@Project.Helper.ResourceHelper.GetLabel(fieldName)
```

Comment: Why are these strings stored in the database? Are they UI strings or content?

Comment: If they are content then do they need to be localised? If they are something that is entered by a user then you wouldn't translate those.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to explain. But I will try: I have a array (EnabledFields), and in this array I have 4 words (I call them fields). The only purpose of these fields is to display in my application. This way I dynamically make a form. So when I delete a field, the form consists of 3 fields, when I add one, then it consists of 4 fields

Comment: Are all these field names known, or do are they essentially random?

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs The are known, they do not change

Comment: You may use something like this as a starting point: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx

Comment: @Stephen Reindl, I actually already had looked ar that before posting me question. But if it is possible, I don't want to move my translations to a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all your translations in your resx files, you can do something like this.

```
/*
  My resource files with the translations in them are named "Lang.ar-EG.resx, Lang.es-MX.resx, ..."
  and reside in my resource folder in the application call "MyApp"

*/


public static class Translator{}
        private static System.Resources.ResourceManager _langResource = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyApp.Resources.Lang", typeof(Language).Assembly);

        public static string Translate(string key, string culture)
        {
            return _langResource.GetString(key, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture));
        }
}
```

and then I can do this in my .cshtml

```
<th>@Translator.Translate("Date", "ar-EG")</th>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `Translator.translate` checks the current culture / language. But I don't understand the the Date / ar-EG part. To me this looks like a static string, translated to ar-EG

Comment: you could replace "Date" with Field (a string value) and the "ar-EG" of the culture you want to translate to.

It will use the string value as a key and look up that key in the resource file for the culture you passed in.

Comment: I have changed your answer a little bit, I have updated my question with the right answer.